# Regex to capture groups from STEP

Tags: regex, step

I got STEP file (can be read as text) which is written in EXPRESS.

The file looks like:

```
#14(REPRESENTATION_RELATIONSHIP($,$,#293,#291)REPRESENTATION_RELATIONSHIP_WITH_TRANSFORMATION(#12)SHAPE_REPRESENTATION_RELATIONSHIP());
#35=MECHANICAL_DESIGN_GEOMETRIC_PRESENTATION_REPRESENTATION('',#180,888.125521);
#25=ADVANCED_BREP_SHAPE_REPRESENTATION('',(#29),#277);
#186=AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D('',#270,#230,#231);
```

I would like to use Regular Expressions to get something like:

```
Match: REPRESENTATION_RELATIONSHIP($,$,#293,#291); Group1: REPRESENTATION_RELATIONSHIP; Group2: $,$,#293,#291
Match: ADVANCED_BREP_SHAPE_REPRESENTATION('',(#29),#277); Group1: ADVANCED_BREP_SHAPE_REPRESENTATION; Group2: '',(#29),#277
```

I am new to Regex and came up with this pattern:
`(\b[A-Z\d]*[_[A-Z\d]*]*)(\((.*?)\))`

which works a little, but for example will just match: `ADVANCED_BREP_SHAPE_REPRESENTATION('',(#29)` instead of `ADVANCED_BREP_SHAPE_REPRESENTATION('',(#29),#277)`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Perhaps like this `#\d+[(=](\w+)\((.*?)\)[;A-Z]` https://regex101.com/r/2wi3ji/1

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use

```
#\d+[(=](\w+)\((.*?)\)[;A-Z]
```

**Explanation**

- `#\d+[(=]` Match #, 1+digits and either `(` or `=`
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars
- `\(` match `(`
- `(.*?)` Capture group 2, match any char as least as possible
- `\)[;A-Z]` Match `)` followed by either `;` or a char A-Z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2wi3ji/1)